# Lower bound on multiplicative norm of Banach algebra.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, representation-theory, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ and $N: A \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ the corresponding multiplicative norm. For $a \in A$, do we have$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} (N(a^n))^{1\over{n}} \le N(a)?$$

Comment: For clarity, can you define $N$ explicitly? Typically the norm of a Banach algebra is referred to as _sub_-multiplicative

Comment: Regardless of whether is submultiplicative or multiplicative, you get $N(a^n) \leq N(a)^n$, so that should solve the problem right?